# Adding to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, observablecollection

If I have a observablecollection in a page that inserts items on a listview. How can I add to that same observablecollection(listview) from a different window(class)? I do not want to use INotifyPropertyChanged and all that. All I'm trying to do is add a item to the existing listview. I have tried literally everything and I can't figure it out. Please any help is appreciated.

CampersPage...(BindingCamper is just my way of basically saying new ObservableCollection()

```
  public partial class CampersPage : Page
{
    MainWindow _parentForm;
    public GridViewColumnHeader currentColumnSorted = null;
    private SortAdorner currentAdorner = null;
    String request1;
    String request2;
    String request3;
    String request4;
   // public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; private set; }


    public CampersPage(MainWindow parent)
    {
        _parentForm = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
        _parentForm.bindings = new BindingCamper();

        for (int i = 0; i < _parentForm.allCampers.Count; i++)
        {


            if (_parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(1) != null && _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(2) != null && _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(3) != null && _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(4) != null)
            {
                request1 = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(1).getName();
                request2 = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(2).getName();
                request3 = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(3).getName();
                request4 = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getRequest(4).getName();

            }

            _parentForm.bindings.Campers.Add(new Camper { FirstName = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getFirstName(), LastName = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getLastName(), Ages = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getAge(), SchoolGrade = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGrade(), Gender = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGender(), bindingRequest1 = request1, bindingRequest2 = request2, bindingRequest3 = request3, bindingRequest4 = request4 });
            //DataContext = _parentForm.bindings;
        }

        DataContext = _parentForm.bindings;



    }
```

---Now I click on a button and a new window comes up where I would like to add a new camper to the listview in CampersPage.

```
      public partial class AddNewCamper : Window
{
    MainWindow _parentForm;


    public AddNewCamper(MainWindow parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parentForm = parentForm;
       // _parentForm.bindings = new BindingCamper();

    }private void btnSubmitNewCamper_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String firstName = txtNewFirstName.Text;
        String lastName = txtLastName.Text;

        int age;
        int grade;
        String newage = comboNewAge.Text;
        if (firstName != "" && lastName != "" && IsNumber(txtNewGrade.Text) && newage != "")
        {
            age = Convert.ToInt16(newage);
            grade = Convert.ToInt16(txtNewGrade.Text);

            // Create New Camper
            Camper person = new Camper(age, grade, boxNewGender.Text, firstName, lastName);

            _parentForm.allCampers.Add(person);
            //This is just adding the camper to the listview. Not sure if it is actually adding it to the database.
            _parentForm.bindings.Campers.Add(new Camper { FirstName = person.getFirstName(), LastName = person.getLastName(), Ages = person.getAge(), SchoolGrade = person.getGrade() });
            //CampersPage p = new CampersPage(_parentForm);
            DataContext = _parentForm.bindings;
```

Do I have to somehow add AddNewCamper's namespace to CampersPage's namespace in xaml?

```
   <ListView  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,12" x:Name ="listViewCampers" ItemsSource="{Binding Campers}" DisplayMemberPath="bindMe" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Column="1">
```

ObservableCollection class:

```
      public partial class BindingCamper  
{  // This class assist in binding campers from listview to the textboxes on the camperspage
    public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Staff> StaffMembers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Schedule> schedule { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }



   public BindingCamper()
    {
      Campers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();
      StaffMembers = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
      schedule = new ObservableCollection<Schedule>();
      Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

   }
```

Comment: @parapura, thats a misleading statement. I can give you thousands of examples where without `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection` WPF can work pretty nicely.

Comment: I am using observableCollection, I just never showed it. _parentForm.Bindings.Camper.  Camper is the ObservableCollection

Comment: I guess my main problem is how do I access CampersPage in AddNewCamper? CampersPage c = new CampersPage() for example isn't working

Comment: Try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your BindingCamper class.

Comment: yea that didn't work..thanks for reply though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't go as far as claiming you're using WPF wrong, but you're certainly making your life difficult. I suggest reading up a bit on **[MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)** pattern - it really makes WPF development easier (here's good starting [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)).

Approach you're using at the moment is not correct on several levels:

- your windows/pages need to have way too much knowledge about each other to work properly
- result of which, is dependency on *parent form* in your child windows (while what you really need is dependency on window **context**, which in fact is **campers list**)
- you need to do too much manual notifications/setting up to achieve your goals (while WPF has great tools to do it automatically)
- you seem to be exposing model (`allCampers`) through view (`MainWindow`)

All of this can be solved with a bit of redesigning:

1. Your views (Main, CampersPage, AddNewCamper) should be dependent on `BindingCamper` class (which essentially could be view model for them), not on each other
2. Same instance of `BindingCamper` should be set as `DataContext` for all of them
3. You **should not** add bindings manually (like you're doing now); all can (and should) be done from XAML

Having above in mind, your `CampersPage` class should look like this:

```
public partial class CampersPage : Page
{
    public CampersPage(BindingCamper camper)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = camper;
    }
}
```

It should by no means initialize data for parent window and set it's binding. This is simply wrong.

Actually, this approach (providing data context through constructor) can be used in all your view classes (`AddNewCamper` and `MainWindow` too, probably).

Now, when you need campers page, say from your main window, it gets very easy:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public void ShowCampers()
    {
        var campersPage = new CampersPage((BindingCampers) this.DataContext);
        // show campersPage
    }
}
```

It is the same with `AddNewCamper` window. Just pass it data context. When you add new camper, add it to `BindingCamper.Campers` list (which is available through data context):

```
// rest of the btnSubmitNewCamper_Click method elided
Camper person = new Camper(age, grade, boxNewGender.Text, firstName, lastName);
((BindingCamper)this.DataContext).Campers.Add(person);
```

That's all. Thanks to combined mechanisms of data binding and observable collection, this new element will immediately be visible both in `MainWindow` and `CampersPage`.

**Edit:**

Code to fetch campers from database should be wrapper with some kind of [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) object (as a part of [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) - I know, lot of ugly *buzzwords*, but luckily they are all related and fairly obvious). For example, you can have a class that will deal with getting campers from database:

```
public class CampersProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Camper> GetAllCampers()
    {
        // here you put all your code for DB interaction
        // and simply return campers
    }
}
```

To give you quick solution, you can once again pass `CampersProvider` to `MainWindow` constructor, call `GetAllCampters` method and build observable collection for `BindingCamper`. However, this is not very MVVM approach. Those stuff usually is handled by view model (yet another, separate class), which at the moment you don't have.

Code you posted requires quite some work, I think it won't be a bad idea if you read a bit about MVVM pattern and try to apply it to your application.

Comment: Yea that does sound pretty easy actually. What about all my other info, like the code where I enter to the database, and all my sort methods. And will the xaml be the same? Thanks for your input, as you can already tell i'm sure, this is my first wpf project lol

Comment: Like in the mainwindow is my allcampers list that comes from the database. I need a for loop to enter all these campers on my observablecollection so that when the program starts up, all the names will be there

Comment: @TMan: as for code to access database and related stuff - this usually goes to DAL (Data Access Layer) part of your program. It's part of business logic, out of ViewModel scope. See my edit on how to deal with this stuff.

Comment: Thanks my man...everybody tells me that MVVM is the way to go but yet all my teachers say MVC is required more. Idk why but anyway thanks for all the input. Unfortunately I don't have the time to fix my code the way it should be. I have made the obvious fixes though and it's working for now. I've looked at several mvvm examples and i really just have a hard time grasping how to do it. Especially b/c everybody examples look different.